# Using D3, how can I transition a line one point at time?

Tags: d3.js, line, transition

I'm working on a visualization project in which one component is a line chart overlayed on a bar graph. I delayed the bar transitions at a time. I would like the line to transition similarly so each point on the line remains "attached" to the bar.

Here's the code for the line:

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
 .x(function(d, i) {
    return xScale(i) + 20;
 })
 .y(function(d) {
    return h - yScale(parseFloat(d.performance));
 });

svg1.append("svg:path").attr("d", line(dataset[0].months));
```

And here's where I transition it:

```
svg1.select("path")
    .transition()
    .ease("linear")
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("d", line(dataset[count].months));
```

I've seen other questions addressing d3 line transitions but none that seem to address my issue, so I hope I'm not a repeater. Thanks in advance!

Note: I did try putting the delay() function in after transition which didn't work. I'm assuming this is because the line is a single `<path>` instead of multiple `<rect>` elements...

Comment: The problem is that the `path` is a single element. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408144/simple-path-transition) should help though.

Comment: I understand, I was hoping I could update the points (the d attribute) one by one. I guess the answer is to append multiple paths and transition them individually. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The alternative is to use the `stroke-dasharray` property and animate that as in the answer to the question I've linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this fell off my radar for a while, but I had some time the other day and figured out one approach for doing the delayed transition...

Here is the [pen](http://codepen.io/gvenech/pen/MaPmyx) I wrote. I [generated](http://beta.json-generator.com/) some random data and created a simple line chart to showing stock prices to play around with. The trick here is instead of iterating through a selection of elements using transition, we iterate through the dataset updating it point by point and transitioning the line as we go:

```
dataset.forEach(function(item, index) {
  let set = dataset.slice();

  // Update the current point in the copy
  set[index].price = newPrice();

  stock_line.transition()
            .delay(index * 500)
            .attr('d', line_generator(set));
});
```

Admittedly this is a bit hacky and possibly overkill, you could just update the whole line at once. Also @Lars mentioned the possibility of using the stroke-dashoffset trick to accomplish this as well. I have played around with that method to animate [drawing the line](http://codepen.io/gvenech/pen/yYNWPe) but I'm not sure how I'd use it to accomplish the same delayed animation shown in the [pen](http://codepen.io/gvenech/pen/MaPmyx). If there is a less hacky implementation please let me know and I'll update this answer.