# Animate the drawing of a curve in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've made a simple bezier curve in d3.
I would like to animate the curve from: starting point to end point.  I would like the animation to take 1.25s?

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x22xE/39/)

**html**

```
<div id="myelement">  
</div>
```

**js:**

```
var svg = d3.select('#myelement').append('svg'),
    curve = svg.append('path')
                 .attr('d', 'M0,200 C400,200 400,200 400,0')
                 .attr('stroke', '#fff')
                    .attr('fill-opacity', 0);

curve.transition()
       .attr('d', 'M0,200 C400,200 400,200 400,0')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a pretty cool way of animating a curve that I saw in an answer to another question https://stackoverflow.com/a/13354478/151212.  With your situation the code would look something like the following:

```
var svg = d3.select('#myelement').append('svg'),
    curve = svg.append('path')
               .attr('d', 'M0,200 C400,200 400,200 400,0')
               .attr('stroke', '#000')
               .attr('fill-opacity', 0);

var length = curve.node().getTotalLength();

curve.attr("stroke-dasharray", length + " " + length)
     .attr("stroke-dashoffset", length)
     .transition()
       .duration(1250)
       .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x22xE/41/)