# Draw a path out gradually from the middle

Tags: svg, d3.js

Suppose I have an arbitrary path drawn with d3

```js
var points = [0, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0];
var svg = d3.select('svg');

var line = d3.svg.line()
            .y(function(d) { return 10*d})
            .x(function(d, t) { return t*20 })
            .interpolate('cubic');

svg.append('path')
  .attr('d', line(points))
  .attr('stroke', 'black')
  .attr('stroke-width', 2)
  .attr('fill', 'none')
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.13/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg style="width: 100%; height: 100%; outline: 1px solid green;"></svg>
```

I want to animate the path drawing out slowly. [I understand how to do it from beginning to end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13353665/cant-make-paths-draw-slowly-with-d3) but in my case I want to start at an arbitrary point on the line and draw outward at the same rate in both direction. 
I can't quite figure out how to do this.

I can utilize `attrTween` and take slices of the array varying by time, but if I do that, the line shifts since I don't know how to set the horizontal offset correctly at each step.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hopefully you're working with the **second** answer on [the page you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13353665/cant-make-paths-draw-slowly-with-d3) (the one by @duopixel), because that's a much better way. If so, then you can make the line start drawing from the middle if you slightly modify the attributes:

```js
var points = [0, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0];
var svg = d3.select('svg');

var line = d3.svg.line()
            .y(function(d) { return 10*d})
            .x(function(d, t) { return t*20 })
            .interpolate('cubic');

var path = svg.append('path')
  .attr('d', line(points))
  .attr('stroke', 'black')
  .attr('stroke-width', 2)
  .attr('fill', 'none');

totalLength = path.node().getTotalLength();

path
 .attr("stroke-dasharray", '0 ' + totalLength)
 .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength/2)
 .transition()
   .duration(2000)
   .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + ' 0')
   .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.13/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg style="width: 100%; height: 100%; outline: 1px solid green;"></svg>
```

#### How it works:

First, consider the original, common scenario of animating the drawing of a path from its start to its end. If `l` is the length of the path (obtained by `path.node().getTotalLength()`) then setting the path's `stroke-dasharray` to `l + ' ' + l` makes the dash and the gap between it and the next dash both equal to `l`. Under these conditions, the path would appear solid, because the dash length being `l` "pushes" the gap past the end of the path. By setting `stroke-dashoffset` to `l`, the above scenario is reversed — the path is entirely a gap (hence invisible) and the dash falls off the path. By transitioning between these 2 states (from one with offset to one without offset), we get a gradual drawing of a line.

Now, to animate from the middle, the dash is defined with length `0` and the gap has a length `l`. So now the line is also completely invisible, due to the 0-length dash and the `l`-length gap . Setting `stroke-dashoffset` to `l/2` moves this 0-length dash halfway down the path. That's the animation starting state. The end state is the reverse `dasharray` where gap is 0 and dash-length is `l`, which renders the line completely solid. To properly transition between these states, we also need to set the end state's `stroke-dashoffset` to `l`. That was something I figured out experimentally, and I'm not sure exactly how to explain it in words. But it works....

Comment: thanks! I had seen that but being unfamiliar with dasharray and dashoffset hadn't seen how it could be used for this. My current strategy is to make a clipPath rectangle and expand it over time but this is way better.

Comment: Actually, I'm still not 100% on why this works. Could you explain?

Comment: @GeorgeMauer NP. I added an explanation.